# Resolved : Calling function from dll in cpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to use a cpp dll's functions in my cpp project, so i've included the dll and the header in my code, I tried two ways to call a function :

- Directly by using its signature, and i got this error :

  ```
  unresolved external symbol "Connect" that is being referenced in the "main" function.
  ```
- Using LoadLibrary to load the dll and GetProcAddress to have a pointer to the function, when i run, an exception throws:

  ```
  Exception thrown at 0x0000000000000000 in MyCode.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0000000000000000.
  ```

The header of dll :

```
#pragma once

#define  _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DllExport extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

SOCKET sock;
WSADATA initialisation_win32;

DllExport int Connect(const char* address, unsigned int timeout);
```

and this is what i tried :

```
// 1st way
int a = Connect("192.168.2.10" , 10);
```

```
// 2nd way
HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("MyDll.dll"));

    
    typedef int (*CNCT)(const char* , unsigned int );
    CNCT Connect = (CNCT)GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, "Connect");

    const char* adrr = "192.168.2.10"; 

    if (Connect(adrr, 10))
        qDebug() << "Card connected";
    else 
        qDebug() << " card disconnected";

 FreeLibrary(hGetProcIDDLL);
```

Comment: From your new thread, your DLL is created by x86. Will the problem be solved if changing to x64?

Answer (score 0):

The approach with  `__declspec(dllexport)` requires conditional compilation in the header file. The implementing DLL has a define that controls if the function is imported or exported.

```
#ifdef IMPLEMENTING_THE_DLL
#define DllAPI extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DllAPI extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

DllAPI int Connect(const char* address, unsigned int timeout);
```

If you include the header file in the consuming project, you get the `__declspec(dllimport)` that causes the load-time-binding behavior.

While building the DLL project an import library (.LIB) is generated. You must add this .LIB file to the consuming project to resolve external reference in the linker error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include code from a `dll` directly into your eveculable, you will need to link the corresponding .lib file into your progect. This tells the linker how to link in the symbol.

You do not need a .lib file to dynamically load a dll. The `LoadLibrary` function does need to be able to find the dll. That you are loading.

You should check the result of LoadLibrary and ensure it is not null before called GetProcAddress. LoadLibrary will fail if the dll cannot be found. This I think is happening in your case.

Comment: right , it's Null, I've verified the path to my dll and it is correct!   do you have any idea whay it can still NULL?

Comment: GetLastError() will give you are reason why LoadLibrary failed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that my DLL was compiled for the x86 architecture and my application was compiled for the x64 architecture, the two were incompatible and the DLL could not be loaded successfully.
I resolved the issue, by recompiling the DLL for the correct architecture (x64), then it is loaded successfully into my application.